# Numerical sorting of every column in a file individually using awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, numeric-data

I'm trying to numerically sort every column individually in a very large file. I need the command to be fast, so I'm trying to do it in an awk command.

Example Input:

```
1,4,2,7,4
9,2,1,1,1
3,9,9,2,2
5,7,7,8,8
```

Example Output:

```
1,2,1,1,1
3,4,2,2,2
5,7,7,7,4
9,9,9,8,8
```

I made something that will do the job (but its not the powerful awk command I need):

```
for i in $(seq $NumberOfColumns); do 
  SortedMatrix=$(paste <(echo "$SortedMatrix") <(awk -F ',' -v x=$i '{print $x}' File | sort -nr) -d ,)
done
```

but it is very slow!
I've tried to do it in awk and I think I'm close:

```
SortedMatrix=$(awk -F ',' 'NR==FNR {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print|"sort -nr"}' File)
```

But it doesn't output columns (just one very long column), I understand why its doing this but I don't know how to resolve it, I was thinking of using paste inside awk but I have no idea how to implement it.

Does anyone know how to do this in awk? Any help or guidance will be much appreciated

Comment: What does "very large" mean? Does it mean all data can't fit into memory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it in a single GNU awk:

```
gawk -F ',' '
    {
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){matrix[i][NR]=$i}
    }
    END{
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){asort(matrix[i])}
        for(j=1;j<=NR;j++){
            for(i=1;i<NF;i++){
                printf "%s,",matrix[i][j]
            }
            print matrix[i][j]
        }
    }
' file
```

- `for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){matrix[i][NR]=$i}`

Multidimensional array (GNU extension) `matrix` gets populated, so that `matrix[i][j]` contains the number of column `i`, row `j`.

- `for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){asort(matrix[i])}`

Sorts each column (GNU extension).

- Finally

  ```
  for(j=1;j<=NR;j++){
      for(i=1;i<NF;i++){
          printf "%s,",matrix[i][j]
      }
      print matrix[i][j]
  }
  ```

Prints a sequence of `a[1],`, `a[2],`, ..., `a[NF-1],`, `a[NF]\n` for each line.

Comment: that works perfectly and its so much faster. I really appreciate the explanation too.

Answer (score 0):

Using `python` :

```
python3 -c 'import sys
L = [] 
with open(sys.argv[1]) as fh:
  L = [line.rstrip("\n").split(",") for line in fh] 
print(*[",".join(j) for j in zip(*[sorted(i,key=int) for i in zip(*L)])],sep="\n")
' file
```

Load the file into a list of lists(matrix) L.

Transpose the data using the zip built-in.

Sort numerically in the transposed matrix  a row at a time.

Transpose once more and print row wise.

**Output:**

```
1,2,1,1,1
3,4,2,2,2
5,7,7,7,4
9,9,9,8,8
```